# Rails redirect controller to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a website with a controller named "Posts".

I would like to redirect "example.com/posts" to "example.com" as they display the same information.

I know this is done in the routes.rb file but after a few hours of searching I don't think I'll figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I am using Rails 4.0 on Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can read all about redirection in routes, here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

```
get '/posts', to: redirect('/')
...
root to: 'posts#index'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned that I already tried a few things, your code being one of them and it's not redirecting.

Comment: In that order? Make sure the redirect is located before others that could impact it (like resources :posts)

Comment: Yes, in that order. I tried what James said as well and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb` file make sure the `root :to` is at the top of your code.  Then you would need to assign a redirect for the GET request you want to always sent there:

```
root :to => 'posts#index'
get '/posts', to: redirect('/')
```

Comment: This didnt work the first time and it still doesnt. How do I downvote you?

Comment: What is not working about it?  Are you getting an error?  Is it just not redirecting?  Please show more code (like a copy of your routes.rb file) and tell us what you are doing that the solution does not work.